# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState,FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

MainActivity have a FragmentTabHost in it ,and five Fragments add to this FragmentTabHost.
Here is the init code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, mFragmentManager, android.R.id.tabcontent);
        // Home
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_HOME).setIndicator(
                        newTabItem(R.drawable.mi_selector_tab_home,
                                R.string.mi_tab_item_milian)),
                TabFateFragment.class, null);

        // Serach
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_SEARCH).setIndicator(
                        newTabItem(R.drawable.mi_selector_tab_search,
                                R.string.mi_navi_title_search)),
                TabSearchFragment.class, null);

        // Msg
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_MSG).setIndicator(
                        newTabItem(R.drawable.mi_selector_tab_msg,
                                R.string.mi_navi_title_msg)),
                TabMsgFragment.class, null);

        // Nearby
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_NEARBY).setIndicator(
                        newTabItem(R.drawable.mi_selector_tab_nearby,
                                R.string.mi_navi_title_nearby)),
                TabNearbyFragment.class, null);

        // Me
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_ME).setIndicator(
                        newTabItem(R.drawable.mi_selector_tab_me,
                                R.string.mi_navi_title_me)),
                TabMeFragment.class, null);
       ......
}
```

And i have read this [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) ,find no FragmentTransaction#commit() in my code.

And i have tried not calling super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) in my Activity.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Here's the **crash log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12134)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2453)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1207)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:778)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:764)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is the above code executed from within onCreate() of your activity? Do you call setup()?

Comment: i forgot to paste it in my code , mTabHost.setup(this, mFragmentManager, android.R.id.tabcontent);

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

The onSaveInstanceState method is called before the Activity is about to be destroyed,to save the Activity data.It causes error to add Fragment to it after the data is saved.The solution is to replace the commit() method with commitAllowingStateLoss(),and the effect is the same.

Comment: but ,there's no FragmentTransaction#commit()  in my code.

Comment: You can abandon using FragmentTabHost ，instead of another method,just like my new answer.

Comment: i am just trying to figure this out ,not simply try another implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You must call setup() before you use addTab():
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: sorry , i called setup() before addTab(), i forgot to paste it in my code , my bad.
mTabHost.setup(this, mFragmentManager, android.R.id.tabcontent);

Answer (score -1):

Using Framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout

            android:id="@+id/tab_content"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

and add a method:

```
private synchronized void replaceFragment() {



        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Workaround for Issue 42601:

        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601

        fragmentTransaction.detach(tabFragments[previousTabIdx]).replace(R.id.tab_content, tabFragments[curTabIdx])

                .attach(tabFragments[curTabIdx]).commitAllowingStateLoss();

        previousTabIdx = curTabIdx;

    }
```

then you can use commitAllowingStateLoss() method.